# Purpose of PostBackUrl in <asp:Button>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

What's the purpose of using `PostBackUrl`?
Let's say I have a `button` which is in *Cart.aspx*:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue Shopping" PostBackUrl="~/Order.aspx"  CssClass="btn" />
```

That means that I will be redirectd to *Order.aspx*, rather than staying on original *Cart.aspx*. Here are my two questions:

1. I also have a `TextBox` in *Cart.aspx*.
   When I click the `button`, the value of the `TextBox` will be posted back to *Order.aspx* rather than original *Cart.aspx*. Now I think we can only get this value if it is posted back to *Cart.aspx*, which contains this `TextBox`.
   What if I want to retrieve this value on the new page?
2. If there is no way to retrieve any input on *Cart.aspx*, why do we need to use *PostBackUrl*? We could just add:

   `Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx")` to the *Cart.aspx.cs*?

Comment: This is what I think what happens when you click the button. The button click is producing a Post event wherein the form on the Page will get posted back to server, let's say Order.aspx page in your case. You can use FormCollection to extract the form values and process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not specify the entry `PostBackUrl`, the button will submit the data back to the same page, in your case it is *cart.aspx*.

The purpose of `PostBackUrl` is a *across-page-posting* of data.

If you specify `PostBackUrl="~/Order.aspx"`, your data will be posted back to your *Order.aspx* page. In your *Order.aspx* page, you will be able to get your `TextBox` (which was in *cart.aspx*) data using:

```
Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1")
```

You can learn more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding (I might be wrong but).

1. Web pages are stateless. The value of your textbox disappears once you leave/ or perform a postback. If you need the values from this page, use cookies, viewstate, sessions or query string to be able to retrieve this value/s.
2. You don't need PostBackUrl but if you prefer to use it, its up to you.
   And yes, Response.Redirect("~/Order.aspx") can be use after you do whatever you need to do in CodeBehind. PostBackUrl is will do the same but will not execute codes that you might need before redirecting.