# ASP.NET I can't Transfer Data to Another Page

Tags: asp.net

[buttonclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cmc5.png)

[2.pageload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSNdW.png)

```
protected void lnkotel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["xd"] = lblotelid1.Text;



        Server.Transfer("~/otelsayfa.aspx");



        Response.Redirect("otelsayfa.aspx?id=" + lblotelid1.Text);
    }
```

---

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblotelid.Text = Session["xd"].ToString();




        var last = PreviousPage;
        if (last != null)
        {
            lblotelid.Text = ((TextBox)last.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
        }
        else
        {
            lblotelid.Text = "no";
        }




        if (Request.QueryString.Get("id") == null)
        {
            lblotelid.Text = "no";
        }
        else
        {
            lblotelid.Text = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        }
```

I tried 3 different variation but all of them have failed. Here is the events after i run this codes one by one:

1st code: I get an error message says: System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.this[string].get, null

2nd code: blank page

3rd code: "no"(because of else condition). If i remove else condition i get same error message as 1st code.

I am trying to solve this for days now. And I cant find any flaws. I honostly appreciate any kind of help now.

edit: I can transfer data from .master page to any .aspx page without any problem. But from .aspx page to diffirent .aspx page, it is just impossible. There is no way.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post source code as image. Include the source code and use the "Code sample" button to format it properly.

Comment: MasterPages wrap regular Pages so they are part of the same page lifecycle if that makes sense. Is session state enabled for the site and /or pages?  Use server transfer  _or_ Response.Redirect, not both as I believe that the redirect in this case is ignored.

Comment: @Enzoaeneas I don't understand what you mean about `code`session state enable`code` but there is a log-in and join page in the site. They work just fine. Also I don't use these codes all together. I just write it like that to show them all. There are 2 pictures on top to prevent them mixed.

Comment: Session state can be selective enabled/disabled for asp.net pages.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307483/purpose-of-postbackurl-in-aspbutton) on SO fits best.

By setting the PostBackUrl on your button, the data from your current page with get sent to your next page as part of the Request collections.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lnkotel1" Text="Click Me!" runat="server" PostBackUrl="page2.aspx"/>
```

To test for the crosspage postback, the [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178139(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) gave this example (I changed it to C#):

```
if(PreviousPage != null)
{
 

    if(PreviousPage.IsCrossPagePostBack == true){
         //Cross-page post
     }
     else 
     {
       //Not a cross-page post
     }
}
```

Then access the value of your original textbox like so:

```
((TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("lblotelid1")).Text
```

Comment: If i am not missing anything, this is the 2nd code in the original post. Unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 1):

I used Listview/Formview and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For sending data by session you should do these in the first page:

Asp form:

```
<asp:Button ID="lblotelid1" runat="server" OnClick="lblotelid1_Click" Text="Yes" />
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void lblotelid1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["xd"] = lblotelid1.Text;

        Response.Redirect("~/otelsayfa.aspx");
    }
```

and on the second page

Asp form:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblotelid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["xd"] != null)
            lblotelid.Text = Session["xd"].ToString();
        else
            lblotelid.Text = "No";
    }
```

Whatever you assign to session["xd"] in the first page, would assign to text of lblotelid label in second page.