# PostBackUrl not working in page with master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

### I have one page with masterpage as 'checkout.aspx' with asp button in bottom

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/allpage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="checkout.aspx.cs" Inherits="CafeSite.checkout" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" runat="server">
B Cafe Checkout
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
    <br>
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="submit.aspx">
        <div style="text-align:center;">

        <p style="color:orangered;font-family:'B Koodak';">
            <span style="color:white;">آقا/خانم:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="last-form-name" value="<% =Page.Request.Params["last-form-name"] %>" /> <% =Page.Request.Params["last-form-name"] %>
        </p>
        <p style="color:orangered;font-family:'B Koodak';">
            <span style="color:white;">به شماره موبایل:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="last-form-phone" value="<% =Page.Request.Params["last-form-phone"] %>" /> <% =Page.Request.Params["last-form-phone"] %>
            &emsp;
            <span style="color:white;">به شماره میز:</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="last-form-sellist" value="<% =Page.Request.Params["last-form-sellist"] %>" /> <% =Page.Request.Params["last-form-sellist"] %>
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" name="order" value="<% =Page.Request.Params["order"] %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<% =Page.Request.Params["count"] %>" />

</div>

<p id="P-Header">
    سفارشات شما
    به شرح ذیل می باشد
</p>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div id="Table-Div" class="container" >
                <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%">
                </asp:Table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" form="form1" CssClass="btn-success rounded" Text="مورد تایید است" PostBackUrl="~/submit.aspx" />
    </div>
</form>

<br>
</asp:Content>
```

my asp button has postbackurl to my submit page but is not working
I don't know how to solve this proble. does anyone know how to solve this and help me?

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307483/purpose-of-postbackurl-in-aspbutton

Comment: thank you but this is not my problem and not useful

Comment: Can master page have its own form tag?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the button not do a postback at all? Does it post but to the wrong page? Also, are there any forms in your master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my question.
In the aspx page with master page the form id is change and so here we should edit form properties on asp button from form1 to aspnetForm.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" form="aspnetForm" CssClass="btn-success rounded" Text="مورد تایید است" PostBackUrl="~/submit.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the form to the master page not the subpage just after the body.

Something like

```
<body>
<form runat="server" id="myformID" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then just add a button to the sub-page and wire it up like normal in the code behind